# What patterns or idioms exist for GUI requring user to provided 4 distinct sets of login creditials?

Tags: user-interface, authentication

**Background:**

The application I am working on happens to be web-based, but the question applies to any GUI.  I need to request three distinct pieces of information from the user four times -- each set is for one of four servers.  There is no commonality between the sign-on for each server, or in other words, the four sets of credentials are unique.

Single-sign-on after the initial logins are done is available.  Once the user logs into a server, the status is persisted on the main view of the application.

This is currently implemented via four separate links, that upon clicking, display a pop-up dialog for the user to enter in their information for the corresponding server they selected.

**Question**:

I was considering this design and trying to think of a way to make the multiple login process easier on the user.   I have a few ideas, but wanted to first see if they compared to what ideas the Stack Overflow community might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- present the user with one form with four sections
- explain why you have to do this
- reassure them that they only have to do this *once*
- validate each section independently
- do not make them click on pop-up links, that's annoying

"i have to ask you four questions. Please poke me in the eye to prompt me to ask each one"

lol

Comment: Interesting idea, I don't agree that form on a window, or a form that happens to be "popped up" is really any different.  

Would the single form have a single "Login" button; if so how do you reasonably display validation and success/failure messages to the user?

Thanks for the response!

Comment: Oh, I think it's a _big_ improvement to save the user 3 clicks that pop up 3 separate dialogs. Each click takes users on average 2.65 seconds, not counting the the server response to show the pop-up, nor the time for the user to visually acquire and orient to the new window. Think of the equivalent CPUs cycles -we'd never tolerate that kind of waste in our algorithms. Why tolerate it for the user's "CPU cycles"?

Comment: Michael,
Agreed, however, I was not saying that the popup form had to be initiated by a user clicking a link (this is just the current implementation).  This could be done by "popping" up the form automatically; then upon each login display success and automatically move to the next login, without having to click another link.

I am trying to think about what would work for the user, not just what won't work for the user, new ideas are welcomed -- your statement is an example of why I asked the original question in the first place.
Thanks for your input,
-bn

Comment: @[bn]: minimize unnecessary motion in the GUI; if all four subforms fit on the screen then pop-ups are unnecessary. good luck!